# how to remove the sub item from the listview

Tags: android

We have created the list view but in that one row is having three Sub Items.Sub item contains id, name,phone_no I want to delete record by using id How to get that id(sub item).I told you I can find the position of row but I am unable to find the ID(sub item).

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,


            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {     

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");          
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(),0,"Cancel");
    }



public boolean onContextItemSelected( MenuItem item){


                 super.onContextItemSelected(item);

         if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){

                 AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)        item.getMenuInfo();
               //find the position of row

       long id= getListView().getItemIdAtPosition(info.position);


              //please write the code here how to get subitem id   
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 int itemId = item.getItemId();
```

It will return the menu item Id